# Count number of 0 values

Tags: sas

Similar to [here](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/09/19/count-the-number-of-missing-values-for-each-variable.html), I can count the number of missing observations:

```
data dataset;
  input a b c;
cards;
1 2 3
0 1 0
0 0 0
7 6 .
. 3 0
0 0 .
;
run;

proc means data=dataset NMISS N;
run;
```

But how can I also count the number of observations that are `0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to count the number of observations that are 0, you'd want to use `proc tabulate` or `proc freq`, and do a frequency count.

If you have a lot of values and you just want "0/not 0", that's easy to do with a `format`.

```
data have;
  input a b c;
cards;
1 2 3
0 1 0
0 0 0
7 6 .
. 3 0
0 0 .
;
run;

proc format;
  value zerof
  0='Zero'
  .='Missing'
  other='Not Zero';
quit;

proc freq data=have;
  format _numeric_ zerof.;
  tables _numeric_/missing;
run;
```

Something along those lines.  Obviously be careful about `_numeric_` as that's all numeric variables and could get messy quickly if you have a lot of them...

Comment: Reading Rick's post, this is very similar to the second part of that post, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I add this as an additional answer.  It requires you to have `PROC IML`.

This uses matrix manipulation to do the count.

`(ds=0)` -- creates a matrix of 0/1 values (false/true) of values = 0

`[+,]`   -- sums the rows for all columns.  If we have 0/1 values, then this is the number of value=0 for each column.

`'`  -- operator is transpose.

`||` -- merge matrices {0} || {1} = {0 1}

Then we just print the values.

```
proc iml;
use dataset;
read all var _num_ into ds[colname=names];
close dataset;
ds2 = ((ds=0)[+,])`;

n = nrow(ds);

ds2 = ds2 || repeat(n,ncol(ds),1);

cnames = {"N = 0", "Count"};
mattrib ds2 rowname=names colname=cnames;

print ds2;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest to use `PROC SQL`.  You will have to use a `UNION` to replicate the `MEANS` output;

Each section of the first `FROM` counts the 0 values for each variable and `UNION` stacks them up.

The last section just counts the number of observations in `DATASET`.

```
proc sql;
select n0.Variable, 
       n0.N_0 label="Number 0", 
       n.count as N
 from (
   select "A" as Variable,
          count(a) as N_0
      from dataset
      where a=0
   UNION 
   select "B" as Variable,
          count(b) as N_0
      from dataset
      where b=0
   UNION
   select "C" as Variable,
          count(c) as N_0
      from dataset
      where c=0
) as n0,
(
    select count(*) as count
    from dataset
) as n;
quit;
```

Comment: Not sure I'd consider all that typing easy ;)

Comment: I would put it in a macro IRL.

Answer (score 1):

there is levels options in proc freq you could use.

```
proc freq data=dataset levels;
table _numeric_;
run;
```